# What happens if I plug a Windows7 hard drive into a different PC?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clone, disk-image

In terms of -
 
a) technical and
 b) licensing considerations, will it work? Obviously many drivers will be incorrect/missing but I'd have expected Windows was able to fix that. So will it run up and then complain or not work at all?

I have a disk with a Windows7 installation I don't want to lose, in a PC I do wish to get rid of. I don't really want to damage/risk the only copy (I have backups of the files, just not the installation) so perhaps I can easily clone the image and then try this with the clone while keeping the original safe?

Comment: The disk will work (with the odd driver to install). The problem arises from a licensing perspective because you will be using a different processor and motherboard. Technically a new PC. The license is probably OEM and is locked to the first machine (CPU/MoBo) it's installed to. You would need to buy a new license to be "legal".

Comment: My PC didn't come with W7 - it's a separate copy. Is this one of those scenarios where you have to pick up the phone and call MS to ask them to transfer your license?

Comment: If it's a retail version then you should be able to reactivate - inevitably over the phone. Just so long as the previous machine doesn't have that particular licensed install of Windows when you re-use or sell on the machine.